# Not able to import Floating Action Button Android sample into eclipse

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm trying to import the [FloatingActionButtonBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/FloatingActionButtonBasic/index.html) Sample Android project into eclips. but it not working out.

Here are the steps which i followed
 - File - > Import -> Existing android code into workspace
 - > Select the project dir - > finish

Comment: I know this won't help you with your question, but why don't you use AndroidStudio? It is much better than Eclipse.

Comment: Any error or not showing any project in dialog?

Comment: When i import i got two projects "Main" & "MAinActivity".Where "Main" is library i think so .

Comment: @blackfizz How do i import there ?

Comment: @Uday In Android Studio.. go to FIle -> Import Sample then browse for "floating action button basic" click next and finish.